# Is $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ with the interval topology a connected space?

Tags: order-theory, gn.general-topology

Is $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ with the [interval topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194642/product-of-posets-with-hausdorff-interval-topology) a connected space? (You find the definition of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200769/antichain-on-mathcalp-omega-fin-of-cardinality-2-aleph-0).)

---

Remark: According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/194685/8628), the interval topology of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ is not Hausdorff, but I haven't found out whether it contains non-trivial clopen sets.

Comment: Can you show us two disjoint non-empty open subsets?

Comment: I can't... But this doesn't mean there aren't such open sets. My intuition for the interval topology on this particular poset is quite poor.

Comment: There aren't, so the space is connected for trivial reasons.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega, are you saying that it is trivial to see that any two nonempty open sets intersect? This is true, as I argue in my answer, but I found it to be a subtle issue.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I'm saying that there are no proper clopen subsets just because there are no disjoint non-empty open subsets (and this is a trivial reason). The fact that non-empty subbasic open sets intersect is not trivial but it is something that anyone interested in this space should be able to prove by himself.

Comment: I see. Meanwhile, I had some fun figuring it out, and I think it is a good problem. Regarding your remark, it doesn't seem to suffice in general for hyperconnectivity to show merely that nonempty sub-basic open sets intersect. For example, consider any Hausdorff space with three points fixed, and consider the sub-basis consisting of all open sets containing two out of three of those points. This generates the same topology, but notice that any two of these subbasic open sets intersect, even when there can be disjoint open sets.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, of course I meant finitely many, no just two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, because any two nonempty open sets have points
in common. And this also shows directly that the space is not
Hausdorff.

From what you describe in the other question, the topology is
generated by the complements of the upper cones $\uparrow
f=[f,1]=\{h\mid h\geq^* f\}$ and the lower cones $\downarrow
g=[0,g]=\{h\mid h\leq^* g\}$, where I am regarding the points as
equivalence classes of functions $f:\omega\to 2$ (but I suppress
the equivalence classes). Thus, a set is open if it is a union of
finite intersections of such cone complements. Let us take those
finite intersections as basic open sets.

What I claim is that any two nonempty basic open sets have
nonempty intersection.

Suppose that $U$ is the intersection of the complements of the
intervals $[f_i,1]$ and $[0,g_j]$ for finitely many $i,j$. So a
function $h:\omega\to 2$ is in $U$ just in case it is not
almost-above any $f_i$ and not almost-below any $g_j$.

Similarly, suppose $V$ is the intersection of the complements of
the intervals $[f_i',1]$ and $[0,g_j']$. So $V$ consists of the
functions $h$ that are not almost-above any $f_i'$ and not
almost-below any $g_j'$.

Assume that $U$ and $V$ are not empty. Thus, we may assume that
the functions $f_i$ are not almost-always $0$ and the $g_j$ are
not almost-always $1$. It follows that there are infinite 
sets $A_i$ and $B_j$ such that $f_i(n)=1$ for $n\in A_i$ and
$g_j(n)=0$ for $n\in B_j$. And similarly $A_i'$ and $B_j'$ for
$f_i'$ and $g_j'$. By shrinking these sets, we may assume that all
$A_i, A_i', B_j, B_j'$ are pairwise disjoint.

Let $h$ be the function that is $0$ on every $A_i$ and $A_i'$ and
$1$ on every $B_j$ and $B_j'$. Thus, $h$ is not above any $f_i$
nor any $f_i'$ and not below any $g_j$ nor $g_j'$. So $h\in U\cap
V$, as desired.

Comment: I fixed an issue with my earlier answer. It seems to me that one must consider finite intersections of cone complements, which I do in the update.

Comment: Nice! In Steen-Seebach's "Counterexamples in topology" such spaces where any two nonempty open sets intersect are called hyperconnected.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks Joel! Is this space also path-connected?