# Is $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/(fin)$ with the interval topology path-connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory

Given a poset $(P,\leq)$ the *interval topology* on $P$ is generated by
$$\{P\setminus\downarrow x : x\in P\} \cup \{P\setminus\uparrow x : x\in P\},$$
where $\downarrow x = \{y\in P: y\leq x\}$ and $\uparrow x = \{y\in P: y\geq x\}$.

Is [$\mathcal{P}(\omega)/(fin)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200769/antichain-on-mathcalp-omega-fin-of-cardinality-2-aleph-0) with the interval topology path-connected?

Comment: According to your definition of "interval topology", it looks as though every subbasic open set is also closed, in any poset ...

Comment: No, otherwise $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ would be disconnected, but it is connected (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200784/is-mathcalp-omega-fin-with-the-interval-topology-a-connected-space?rq=1 ). My question is if it is even path-connected

Comment: Oh, I misread the definition, sorry.

Comment: If we use $J=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ in place of $\omega$, is the map from the unit interval $x\in[0,1]$ to the rational cut $\{q\in J\mid q<x\}$ a path from $\emptyset$ to $J$ in $P(J)/\text{Fin}$? If so, then we could translate this all around and path-connect any point to the top, deducing path-connectedness of $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$.  That is, we basically map reals to their cut in the rationals. Is it a path?

Comment: It seems to me that it is; I'll write up something later when I have a chance.

Comment: That would be great @JoelDavidHamkins, this has been open for some time. Thanks in advance for your effort!

Comment: Well, further consideration shows that this is not a path after all, and I now expect that this space is not path-connected.